# C# method to convert html-markup into JavaScript-compatible string

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

I believe there should exist a known method for converting this:

```
   <div class="singlePane pane">
     <div class="tripleColumn"> <!-- TODO:  -->
     <div class="col">

    <div class="captionedLink">
     <div class="icon" style="background-position: -26px 0px;"> blah blah
```

INTO THIS:

```
    \r\n \u003Cdiv class=\"singlePane pane\"\u003E\r\n \u003Cdiv class=\"tripleColumn
\"\u003E \u003C!-- TODO --\u003E\r\n \u003Cdiv class=\"col\"\u003E\r\n 
\n\u003Cdiv class=\"captionedLink\"\u003E\n \u003Cdiv class=\"icon\" style=\"background-
position: -26px 0px\"\uBLAH BLAH
```

Please, please reveal it to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why would you keep all the whitespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently using (a slightly modified version of) [Rick Strahl's JavaScript encoding](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/114530.aspx).
Works well for me!

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means the fastest way to do this (static `Regex.Replace` method is slow compared to a Regex instance.  But I've done this in order to turn any html into a string that can be used for `document.write`:

```
string htmlResult = "/*string*/";
htmlResult = Regex.Replace(htmlResult, @"\r\n", " ");
htmlResult = Regex.Replace(htmlResult, @"\n", " ");
htmlResult = Regex.Replace(htmlResult, @"\s{2,}", " ");
htmlResult = Regex.Replace(htmlResult, @"\\", @"\\");
htmlResult = Regex.Replace(htmlResult, @"[']", @"\'");
```

This also does away with all your carriage returns and unnecessary whitespace.